# Поделить html файл на страницы

Tags: javascript, html, page

Как разбить html файл на несколько страниц? Допустим у меня есть блоки `<div>` которые, как, допустим вопросы на этом ресурсе, и нужно было чтобы на одной странице было максимум 10 блоков таких. И если я добавляю новый, то последний смещался автоматически на новую страницу(снова же как на данном ресурсе). Чтобы вручную это все время не перестанавливать и все это делалось автоматически.

Comment: Используй gulp для сборки нескольких файлов в один и храни по одному блоку в файле. Сами страницы создавай из этих файлов gulp'ом.

Comment: Самый правильный способ - управлять всем этим с помощью бэкенда. Если у вас предполагается возникновение новых блоков - то вам нужно хранить данные в базе данных для удобства их добавления и отображения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно, чтобы осуществлялась пагинаця каких-нибудь дивов на одной странице, то достаточно будет простого js-пагинатора. Можно написать самому, можно использовать готовый, например [jquery pagination](http://dbmast.ru/simplepagination-js-legkij-jquery-plagin-dlya-sozdaniya-paginacii).

Если вам надо автоматически генерить страницы с разными url на основе какого-то файла, наполненного дивами, то используйте вариант со сборщиком. Либо генерите страницы на серверной стороне.